# how to change the array [1,2,3,4] to [1,3,4]

Tags: javascript

any simply way ?

this is my code:

```
var a=[1,2,3,4]
        a.slice(0,1)
        alert( a)
```

and it print [1,2,3,4]

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`splice()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wctc5k7s(v=VS.85).aspx) method:

```
var a=[1,2,3,4];
a.splice(1,1);
alert(a);        // -> 1,3,4
```

Answer (score 3):

You should rather use `splice` instead of `slice`:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
a.splice(1, 1);
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.